# Call a Javascript function with argument (in a specific file) from PHP with parameter

Tags: javascript, php, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I've a JS file with function named `graph_poids2`, this function has an argument named `dayr`:

File `graph.js`:

```
$(function graph_poids2(dayr) {
  alert(dayr);
  chaine1='../graph/data_today_poids2.php?day=';
  alert(chaine1.concat(dayr));
  $.getJSON(chaine1.concat(dayr), function (data) {  // on récupère les data du json.

  etc..
}
```

In my Main PHP file and before exisiting an argument in JS function `graph_poids2`, I called the JS fuction like that:

```
<script src="../graph/graph.js"></script>
```

BUT now how to do with the JS argument?
I've modified the PHP file like that, but it's not working :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var dayr='<?php echo "2017-10-31"; ?>'; </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> graph_poids2(dayr); </script>
<script src="../graph/graph_today_poids2.js"></script>
```

How to do , i've tried many things and looked on the web but nothing help me...
Any ideas , please?

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, you can see a develop console. Then refresh the tab, you can get specific error logs. Post the errors in your question we would help you.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the appending of your scripts to the page. Now `graph_poids2(dayr);` gets called before the script with the function has been added to the DOM.

```
<script src="../graph/graph_today_poids2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var dayr='<?php echo "2017-10-31"; ?>'; 
    graph_poids2(dayr);
</script>
```

Script blocks are parsed in line with the page flow. JavaScript content within a script block is parsed according to the rules set for the language. Functions and `var`s get hoisted to the top. So declaring a function below the line that calls the function isn't a problem within a script block, but not when the function is called from another script block.

> also it is good practice to use an onload event to make sure all necessary scripts have been loaded. Jquery makes this easy with `$(document).ready(«function»)` but in Vanilla JS you can do this to with the [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event.

Comment: F12 Console, said the function graph_poids2 isn't defined, and alert popup doesn"t display a correct value for dayr argument

Comment: Well check if there is a `404` error on your resource or maybe even a script error in `graph_today_poids2.js.`

Comment: If I fix dayr arguemnt in JS function like : dayr='2017-11-01';, the script is well executed (with inside function fixed arguement), but remaining the the warning graph_poid2(dayr) not defined.